# Disable Digital Signature Certification or issue a blanket certificate for all users on an InfoPath form?

Tags: email, certificate, forms, microsoft-infopath, signature

We have some Time-Off request forms that are sent through InfoPath 2007 via e-mail and it goes down the verification line (e.g. Employee signs and it gets sent to their supervisor then it gets sent to HR for final sign off). The problem we're having is when we open file the signatures give us an error which lags and freezes up InfoPath for a while until it checks all the UN-Verified signatures which wastes a lot of time with 100+ employees. So, is there a way to issue a blanket certificate that will make everyone's signature trusted OR can we disable the verification of the signature all together somehow?

See image below for our error we receive.

[Error that eventually pops up after a while](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKP41.png)

I would just like to make the error to stop somehow by either accepting all signatures without certificate or manual verificationm etc.